# The action 'favicon' could not be found for Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For every error in my syste, I get a notification from the system.

Problem is that for **every** error I get **2** errors, and one is always:

```
The action 'favicon' could not be found for XXXXController.
```

What is the meaning of this error, and where does it come from?

I think it might be connected to some mis-configuration, but I am not sure where exactly.

This is the full message:

```
-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:116:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  exception_notification (3.0.1) lib/exception_notifier.rb:41:in `call'
  wicked_pdf (1.1.0) lib/wicked_pdf/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__905330616415270423__call__122903620689906054__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.7.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:140:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.7.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:249:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.7.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:189:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.7.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.7.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'

-------------------------------
System error:
-------------------------------

  ERROR: Failed to generate exception summary:

  ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing partial exception_notifier/system_error with {:locale=>[:hb], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :axlsx, :rjs]}. Searched in:
    * "/var/www/html/paam/app/views"
    * "/home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views"


  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `find_template'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:333:in `find_partial'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:222:in `render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/prototype-rails-3.2.1/lib/prototype-rails/rendering.rb:8:in `render_with_update'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb:9:in `block in __home_paam__rvm_gems_ruby_______p____gems_exception_notification_______lib_exception_notifier_views_exception_notifier_exception_notification_text_erb__2382212765454580501_58769400'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb:7:in `map'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb:7:in `__home_paam__rvm_gems_ruby_______p____gems_exception_notification_______lib_exception_notifier_views_exception_notifier_exception_notification_text_erb__2382212765454580501_58769400'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:684:in `block in collect_responses_and_parts_order'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/collector.rb:26:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/collector.rb:26:in `custom'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb:10:in `text'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/notifier.rb:176:in `block in compose_email'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:685:in `collect_responses_and_parts_order'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:636:in `mail'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/notifier.rb:175:in `compose_email'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/notifier.rb:104:in `exception_notification'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:457:in `process'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:452:in `initialize'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `new'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `method_missing'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier.rb:49:in `rescue in call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/exception_notification-3.0.1/lib/exception_notifier.rb:41:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/wicked_pdf-1.1.0/lib/wicked_pdf/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__905330616415270423__call__122903620689906054__callbacks'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/quiet_assets-1.1.0/lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-cache-1.7.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:140:in `forward'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-cache-1.7.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:249:in `fetch'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-cache-1.7.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:189:in `lookup'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-cache-1.7.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-cache-1.7.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  /home/paam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Comment: Can you add the full message of that error?

Comment: Just added, Thanks.

Comment: @NoamB.  Do you have something like `favicon_link_tag('favicon.ico')` in your layout?

Comment: Yes, it's my websites favicon and it is working in my website.